# How to apply config for Elasticsearch deploy on K8s?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a trouble in change Elasticsearch config that deployed in K8s.
I want to apply this config for my Elasticsearch node

```
# Force all memory to be locked, forcing the JVM to never swap
bootstrap.mlockall: true

## Threadpool Settings ##

# Search pool
threadpool.search.type: fixed
threadpool.search.size: 20
threadpool.search.queue_size: 100

# Bulk pool
threadpool.bulk.type: fixed
threadpool.bulk.size: 60
threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 300

# Index pool
threadpool.index.type: fixed
threadpool.index.size: 20
threadpool.index.queue_size: 100

 # Indices settings
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 30%
indices.memory.min_shard_index_buffer_size: 12mb
indices.memory.min_index_buffer_size: 96mb

# Cache Sizes
indices.fielddata.cache.size: 15%
indices.fielddata.cache.expire: 6h
indices.cache.filter.size: 15%
indices.cache.filter.expire: 6h

# Indexing Settings for Writes
index.refresh_interval: 30s
index.translog.flush_threshold_ops: 50000
```

To deploy Elasticsearch in K8s, I follow two step:
Step 1: Create .yml file, like this

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: esc-lamtest
  namespace: lamtest
spec:
  version: 7.9.0
  nodeSets:
    - name: basic-1
    count: 3
    config:
        node.master: true
        node.data: true
        node.ingest: true
        # Search pool
        thread_pool.search.queue_size: 50
        thread_pool.search.size: 20
        thread_pool.search.min_queue_size: 10
        thread_pool.search.max_queue_size: 100  
volumeClaimTemplates:
- metadata:
    name: elasticsearch-data
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 150Gi
    storageClassName: vnptit-nfs
podTemplate:
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: elasticsearch
      env:
      - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
        value: -Xms4g -Xmx4g
      resources:
        requests:
            memory: 0Gi
            cpu: 0Gi
        limits:
            memory: 0Gi
            cpu: 0Gi
```

http:
tls:
selfSignedCertificate:
disabled: true

Step 2: I run command line:

```
kubectl apply -f lamtest.yaml
```

But I can only app config for "Search pool".
When I apply config for `# Bulk pool # Index pool # Indices settings # Cache Sizes and # Indexing Settings for Writes`, my Elasticsearch fail and here is my logs

```
"Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [thread_pool.bulk.queue_size] did   you mean any of [thread_pool.get.queue_size, thread_pool.write.queue_size, thread_pool.analyze.queue_size, thread_pool.search.queue_size, thread_pool.listener.queue_size]?", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:544) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:489) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:460) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:431) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsModule.<init>(SettingsModule.java:149) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:385) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:277) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
"\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [thread_pool.bulk.size] did you mean any of [thread_pool.get.size, thread_pool.write.size, thread_pool.analyze.size, thread_pool.search.size]?", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:544) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:489) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:460) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:431) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsModule.<init>(SettingsModule.java:149) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:385) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:277) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]", 
 "\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]"] } 
 uncaught exception in thread [main] 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [thread_pool.bulk.type] please check that any  required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings 
 at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:544) 
 at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:489) 
at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:460) 
at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:431) 
at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsModule.<init>(SettingsModule.java:149) 
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:385) 
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:277) 
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) 
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) 
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) 
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) 
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) 
at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) 
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127) 
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) 
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) 
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
```

For complete error details, refer to the log at /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/esc-lamtest.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is very clear, that you have not defined the proper config for other **threadpools**,  Please notice the first line of your error msg carefully.

> "Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting
> [thread_pool.bulk.queue_size] did   you mean any of
> [thread_pool.get.queue_size, thread_pool.write.queue_size,
> thread_pool.analyze.queue_size, thread_pool.search.queue_size,
> thread_pool.listener.queue_size]?",

You have defined bulk queue size as `thread_pool.bulk.queue_size`, which is not correct and as you can read [threadpools in ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html) , there is no, threadpool for `bulk`, **instead it uses `write` threadpool for `bulk` requests, from the same doc, hence chaning this to `thread_pool.write.queue_size` would work for this config.**

> **write** For single-document index/delete/update and bulk requests.
> Thread pool type is fixed with a size of # of allocated processors,
> queue_size of 10000. The maximum size for this pool is 1 + # of
> allocated processors.

**Now in order to fix this for `bulk`, `Index` and other settings, please verify that you are using the correct names for their config**s, `threadpools` can be obtained from any running ES instance and you can easily construct the corresponding config.

http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats?pretty  gives the all the `threadpools` and some are listed below.

```
"thread_pool": {
"analyze": {
"threads": 1,
"queue": 0,
"active": 0,
"rejected": 0,
"largest": 1,
"completed": 1
},
"ccr": {
"threads": 0,
"queue": 0,
"active": 0,
"rejected": 0,
"largest": 0,
"completed": 0
},
}
```